# Properties files not found running java through Ant

Tags: ant, properties

the structure of the example project is:

```
.
|-- ./build
|   `-- ./build/TestAntLoadFile.class
|-- ./build.xml
|-- ./dist
|   |-- ./dist/icpFinder.jar
|   `-- ./dist/icp-finder.properties
|-- ./icp-finder_bak.properties
`-- ./src
    `-- ./src/TestAntLoadFile.java
```

and the code getting the properties file is:

```
 public class TestAntLoadFile {
    private static final String CUSTOMER_CONFIG_FILE_NAME 
          = "icp-finder.properties";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream custumerConfigIn = TestAntLoadFile.class.
                getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CUSTOMER_CONFIG_FILE_NAME);

        System.out.println("custumerConfigIn: " + custumerConfigIn);
    }

 }
```

and build.xml core contend is :

```
    <path id="run.classpath">
    <fileset dir = "${dist.dir}" >
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
        <include name="./icp-finder.properties"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="TestAntLoadFile">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="run.classpath"/>
        </classpath>

    </java>     
</target>
```

the project run well in eclipse, Has anybody got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than including the properties file itself in the classpath, you need to include the directory it resides in, something like this for example:

```
<path id="run.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}" >
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <dirset dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <pathelement path="${dist.dir}" />
</path>
```

Comment: I remove the "./", as you told, and the setting is :                                         <include name="icp-finder.properties"/>. but it failed again.

Comment: @mn190 - apologies, I have updated my answer.  I'd somehow ignored the fact that you were building a classpath rather than just a fileset.  You don't include properties files themselves in the classpath, you include containing jars and/or directories.